# Cannot catch System.Printing.PrintQueueException

Tags: c#, printing, exception

My app is throwing a System.Printing.PrintQueueException, I can catch it in a try-catch block by using "exception" but I cannot handle the specific exception because it is not recognised;

This works;

```
        try
        {
            MethodThatThrowsException();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Handle();
        }
```

But this won't build (intellisense state that it 'Cannot resolve symbol 'PrintQueueException'');

```
        try
        {
            MethodThatThrowsException();
        }
        catch (System.Printing.PrintQueueException)
        {
            Handle();
        }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you include the reference to the assembly?! In which context are you trying to use that code? Web?

Comment: There's got to be a canonical for this somewhere.  In order to use a type, you need to reference the assembly for that type.  You can find the assembly by looking up the type in the msdn docs for it.  The assembly is listed near the top of the page.  Right click on the References node in the project and add a reference to its assembly.  Then, once you've done that, grab a copy of CLR Via C#, skip to chapter 4, and start reading.  You'll be exponentially more knowledgeable in c# within 8 hours.  Why would you *not* do it?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx

Comment: If you are using that code in the context of a Windows Service or ASP.NET application you cannot use classes in the System.Printing namespace:

Classes within the System.Printing namespace are not supported for use within a Windows service or ASP.NET application or service. Attempting to use these classes from within one of these application types may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time exceptions.

Comment: ...But that won't prevent you from catching exceptions of that type.  You might have issues with using types in an MTA, for example.  Certain types in that assembly require they be used within STA threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the `ReachFramework.dll` assembly, which contains the `PrintQueueException`. See the MSDN documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueueexception(v=vs.110).aspx